# Send an array of strings to specific field in body through PUT method (node)

Tags: reactjs, api, put

I've a problem I don't have an idea how to resolve it. I've a database called 'usuarios'(users) with a specific field called 'alimentos' (foods) where I plan to insert all the foods the user is allergic to. The route I've in my back to actualize this field looks like this:

```
router.put("/", authenticateJWT, (req, res)=> {
    const id = req.usuario.userID;

    let camposActualizar = {};
    
     camposActualizar = {...req.body};

    Usuarios.findByIdAndUpdate(id, camposActualizar)
        .then(()=> {
            return Usuarios.findById(id);
        })
        .then((usuarioActualizado)=> {
            res.send(usuarioActualizado);
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
})
```

in my react front, I've called the API with Axios. I have an API.jsx file with basic configuration:

```
export const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL,
    timeout: 6000,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
});
```

and then i try to call this api with PUT method like this (I try to push allergiesIDs array, and i tried many different ways but it just didnt work):

```
 let allergiesIDs = [];
    landingAllergies.map((id) => allergiesIDs.push(id.id));

    const putAllergies = () => {
        API.put('usuarios', allergiesIDs).then((req,res) =>{
            const alimentos = req.body.alimentos
        })
            .then(() => {
                alimentos: allergiesIDs
            })
    }
```

Does someone have any idea about how to push allergiesIDs array to a specific field (foods) in the database? I appreciate so much your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

And here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Combining this two will bring you to the solution, that will be something like this:

```
YourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: yourObjectIdHere },
    { $push: { yourFieldName: { $each: theFoodArrayYouReceived } } },
    { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
)
```